# Upload Adventure Works Database 2014 into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-recommendation

Can I upload Adventure Works 2014 DB mdf file into my sql server 2012?

Answer (score 2):

No.

SQL Server does not allow you to restore or attach a database from a higher version of SQL Server to a lower version  of SQL Server.

See [How to migrate a SQL Server database to a lower version](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2810/how-to-migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-a-lower-version/) for more information.